# Name after Disney movie

Tags: consumer-protection

I have a thoroughbred racing horse and I would like to name the filly. I have chosen the name Elena of Avalor. An animated movie from Disney.
Am I allow in usage of the name? Please advise.

Comment: You'd better check with the Jockey Club as one of the naming restrictions is ["No names clearly having commercial significance, such as trade names"](https://www.thoughtco.com/naming-a-thoroughbred-horse-1880228).

Answer (score 1):

You'll be fine.

You cant copyright names, but you can trademark them.

But the disney character has nothing to do with racing horses, so won't be violating their trademark